# jQuery - extend css()

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

**As jQuery `.css()` dont work if I want to get css value of `margin`, `padding`.**

I found a jquery code which solve this this bug.

Please help me to extednd jquery `.css()` by adding this code:

```
$.each(['border', 'margin', 'padding'], function (i, name) {
        $.fn[name] = function (value) {
            if (value) {
                if (value.top !== undefined) {
                    this.css(name + '-top' + (name === 'border' ? '-width' : ''), value.top);
                }
                if (value.bottom !== undefined) {
                    this.css(name + '-bottom' + (name === 'border' ? '-width' : ''), value.bottom);
                }
                if (value.left !== undefined) {
                    this.css(name + '-left' + (name === 'border' ? '-width' : ''), value.left);
                }
                if (value.right !== undefined) {
                    this.css(name + '-right' + (name === 'border' ? '-width' : ''), value.right);
                }
                return this;
            }
            else {
                return {top: num(this.css(name + '-top' + (name === 'border' ? '-width' : ''))),
                        bottom: num(this.css(name + '-bottom' + (name === 'border' ? '-width' : ''))),
                        left: num(this.css(name + '-left' + (name === 'border' ? '-width' : ''))),
                        right: num(this.css(name + '-right' + (name === 'border' ? '-width' : '')))};
            }
        };
    });
```

**Hre is the fiddle which shows that jquery `.css()` fails getting value of padding and margin, in firefox browser**

http://jsfiddle.net/howtoplease/fMTsW/4/

Comment: What are you asking? Did you try the code? Did it not work or something?

Comment: yes work in chrome but fails in firefox, I want to use above code to extend `css()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a solution, have a look at this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       ....
           $('[name='+this.name+']').val(marginT);
           .....
       }else{         
        this.value = $('h3').css(this.name);
       }
    });
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fMTsW/10/)

The above code is my own logic, 
I have also implemented the code that you have provided.

[Your Plugin function](http://jsfiddle.net/qTCTm/)

This plugin also has issue, check the console.log displayed.

Comment: demo fails if margin:40px 50px;